# Java BufferedWriter doesn't write to file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I want to write some string to file (use Java 8). This code snippet compiles without any errors, but doesnt write to file....i'm noob ofcorz...any suggestion?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Main {
    private static final String FILENAME = "C:\\IntelliJfiles\\write-to- 
                                              file\\src\\pl\\sca\\file.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String str = "kal";

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
            FileWriter(FILENAME));
            writer.write(str);

            System.out.println("Done");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There's no file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should close the file after you write to it. Never leave a resource open. And you should be using "Try with resources"

Comment: Does `writer.close();` help?

Comment: try-with-resources or add `writer.close();`

Comment: writer.close(); help, thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not write to the file until you close it - writing to the disk is time consuming so it waits until enough characters are written before doing actually putting them in the file. That's what the Buffered in `BufferedWriter` means. If you close it, it will "flush" the buffer onto the disk.

You can close it yourself using `writer.close()`

Or you can make use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which will automatically close the writer:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\IntelliJfiles\\write-to-file\\src\\pl\\sca\\file.txt");
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)){
    bw.write("kal");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `BufferWriter` is [Files.write(Path, byte[], OpenOption...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) if you aim at writing to a file only once.

```
String str = "test";
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");

try {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardsCharsets.UTF_8);
    Files.write(path, bytes);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle file absence.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle other exceptions related to io.
}
```

**Note**: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117406/java-bufferedwriter-doesnt-write-to-file/50117480?noredirect=1#comment87252852_50117480) catching `Exception` doesn't indicate file absence in all cases. Catch `FileNotFoundException` if you want to handle file absence or `IOException` for all exceptional conditions related to io.

Comment: thanks fot your mention,  thought IOException is enough:)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
try {
            String str = "kal";
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
            FileWriter(FILENAME));
            writer.write(str);
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Done");

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the writer, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
String str = "kal";

// we can use try-with-resources from java 7
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME))) {
    writer.write(str);
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

Or simply add `writer.close()`:

```
writer.write(str);
writer.close();
```

Comment: A small improvement: Catching an exception doesn't indicate that the file is missing in all cases. You should catch an `FileNotFoundException` if you are interested in this "event" and catch `IOException`s for other error conditions you might encounter while dealing with io. Furthermore you can move the catch clause to the inner try block.

Comment: @sn42 I've just copied the code from the question and supplemented it :)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Sure it's a good answer solving the original problem. A great answer would either state that the code you provide has a bug (Failing IO-operations don't indicate file absence in all cases) or change the original code and explain why this changes are necessary or desirable. Especially for developers starting with Java these advices would be valuable I guess. FYI this is an improvement no correction :)